# quicksort in c++ and how did I get here

Tags: c++, quicksort

Hi I'm a complete begginner in algorithms and I had quicksort to do as an assignement, I tried for hours but it all seems complicated and the resources given by the teacher were wrong.
Now my problem is, I don't know why this code works

this is my partitioning algorithm

```
int partition(int arr[], int l, int h){
int pivot = arr[h];
cout << "pivot = " << pivot << endl; 
int i, j;

i=l;
j=h;
while (i<j){
    while (arr[i]<pivot){
        i++;
    }
    while(arr[j]>pivot){
        j--;
    }
    cout <<"on echange " << arr[i] << " et " << arr[j] << endl ;
    swap(arr[i],arr[j]);

}
arr[j] = pivot;
return j;
```

}

```
void quicksort(int arr[], int l, int h){
    int j;
    if (l<h){
            j = partition(arr, l, h);
            cout << "recursion haut"<< endl;
            quicksort(arr, l, j-1);
            cout << "recursion bas" << endl;
            quicksort(arr, j+1, h);
    }

}
```

Now what I don't understand is that most partitioning algorithms seem to call the "swap" function 2 times, the first to swap the smaller than the pivot elements to the left and the bigger than the pivot to the right and the second to place the pivot in the i index. Mine works by only calling this function once which completely confuses me and I just get overwelmed everytime i try to go step by step.

I thought i should initialize j at h-1 since h is the pivot index but if i do that than the code doesn't run on my machine, and if I check if i<j before the swap, the code doesn't run either. I got here by accident and it's making my brain hurt to understand whats going on
Algorithms on the internet seem to initialize i at the left index -1 for some reason and then only increment when a certain condition is met, which is not what i saw in class. Also I've added plenty of "couts" on my code to see what was going on but i still don't get it.

Comment: A good way to understand your code is using the debugger and checking line for line. Questions you can ask yourself during this are:
Do the values in my variables change in this line?
What does this line do to my variables? and so on

Comment: I like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8) explanation the most.